# Expect: How to disambiguate dual meaning?

Tags: disambiguities

There seems to be two different meanings of the word 'expect' in common spoken English.

For example, 'I expect you to tidy your room this evening'. This is like a demand, in that the person speaking is asking someone to do something, and almost treat it like an order.

The second meaning is in a sentence like 'I expect it's going to rain tomorrow'. This isn't an order, merely relating what they think will happen in the future.

I don't believe either of the above examples would be ambiguous to a native speaker due to context, but the sentence 'I expect not to hear from you again' would be.

Is there a way to disambiguate this last use?

Comment: In conversation, by the emphases and cadences. But not in print without context. English is far from perfect (however one defines 'perfect').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Understood, but I'd be using this phrase in text.

Comment: use a synonym construct that doesn't bear this ambiguity: I hope not to hear form you again vs I'll probably not be hearing from you again

Comment: This kind of question is what the Brits call taking the piss. There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: “I expect not to hear from you again” would not be very ambiguous either: it is a polite way of saying, “Don't contact me again”. The other meaning, “I have no expectation of hearing from you again, but it may still happen”, would be “I don't expect to hear from you again”. @Lambie There certainly is a difference in meaning. I don't see what this has to do with taking the piss.

Comment: No, there isn't a difference. All three are about what the speaker's expectation is with regard to a person or a future situation. The only difference is the object (not grammatical) of that expectation, what it refers to....but meaning-wise it is the same.

Comment: @P.O. That is probably the best course of action, but I was hoping for an answer which still used the work expect.

Comment: @Lambie The fact that all the definitions of _expect_ are about a person’s expectations for/of something doesn’t change the fact that they mean different things. That’s not how semantics work.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I see. How do semantics "work"?

Comment: @Lambie: there is a huge difference in pragmatic meaning. But they're generally distinguished by grammar.  If your boss says *"I expect you to finish this job three days early,"* you work your ass off. If your boss says *"I expect that you'll finish this job three days early,"* you probably feel pleased that he has such great confidence in your abilities.

Comment: @Lambie You can almost always move up or down in the level of detail or abstraction of an idea expressed by a given phrasing or word to consider its similarities and dissimilarities with another phrasing or word. Two different phrasings or words almost never carry _precisely_ the same meaning, but if they are even tangentially related, you can almost always abstract away enough detail that they become roughly equivalent. But dismissing a difference in a more detailed meaning by referring to a more abstract meaning than that referenced is not a good way to approach semantics.

Comment: The easiest way to clarify that the sentence is meant as a prediction rather than as a command is to reword so you can include a degree of uncertainty: *I expect (that) I (**might** / **probably will**) not hear from you again.* The suggested "that" version is good, but might be still too subtle. This could be a UK/US difference (I'm an AmE speaker). To make it definitely a command, verging on a threat, add a tag: *I expect not to hear from you again—**understood?*** Or ***Got it?*** if you're feeling especially belligerent.

Comment: @Peter Shor Those two sentences you have use expect the same way. The difference in them is not in the word expect. You can put in: I have the expectation that X versus I have the expectation that [you x] and expect means the same thing. The semantic trait is for: to have the expectation that in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences you mention correspond to the following definitions:

> **Expect** *verb*
>   1 Regard (something) as likely to happen.
>   1.4 Require (someone) to fulfil an obligation.
>   *[with object and infinitive] ‘we expect employers to pay a reasonable salary’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expect)

When an expectation is made of a person, it tends to be taken as a demand. When it is made regarding an event, it tends to be taken as an expression of likelihood.

Consider the following examples:

1. A: I expect you to pass this exam. B: Yes, Sir!
2. A: I expect that you will pass this exam. B: Thank you!

These follow the pattern described above: *expect [person]* implies a demand; *expect [event]* implies likelihood.

However, consider changing the second example's response to that of the first:

3. A: I expect that you will pass this exam. B: Yes, Sir!

The sentence that was treated as an expression of likelihood is now treated as a demand.

**The attitude of the speaker, their general demeanour, and the context in general must all be taken into account**. As (2) and (3) demonstrate, there is no simple test for disambiguation that works in all situations. However, the earlier comment regarding the difference between (1) and (2) provides a useful rule of thumb.

---

You ask about disambiguating the following, which I will number for convenience:

> 4. I expect not to hear from you again.

Consider the following similar sentences, coloured with a little context:

5. I was looking for you for so long. I expected not to hear from you again.
6. Explain yourself! I expected not to hear from you again.
7. He was poorly treated. I expect not to hear from him again. You should apologise anyway.
8. Tell him I was poorly treated. I expect not to hear from him again.
9. Tell him I was poorly treated, though I expect not to hear from him again.

The only difference in the sentence between (4) and (5) is the tense of *expect*. However, the context of (5) makes clear that the expectation was an expression of likelihood, not a demand. In (6), keeping the sentence from (5) but changing the context gives a different sense - that of a past demand, perhaps from a headmaster to a recalcitrant trouble-maker.

Between (4) and (7), the difference is *you* vs *him*, just a switch in pronouns. The context of (7) contains no hint of a demand (of *him*). It's purely situational. Changing just the context to that of (8) colours the sentence as part of a sequence of demands. However, if we replace the first full stop with *though* (9), the sense is reversed and it's no longer a demand.

We now return to (4). By **idiomatic usage** (though probably more BrE than AmE), the context this suggests is closest to that of (8); it's read as a **demand**. To read it otherwise would require something explicit in the context, but even the following sits awkwardly as purely an expression of likelihood:

10. She saw him board the boat headed for uncharted waters and whispered sadly, "So this is our final goodbye. I expect not to hear from you again."

Comment: Good answer, but I wonder if you could expand with slightly with my specific ambiguous sentence? 'I expect not to hear from you again'

Comment: Also you're point about event vs person is astute. But in the sentence 'i expect not to hear from you're there's ambiguity as there's an event ('hear from you') and person ('you').

Comment: @IanNewson Apologies for having left that out. I've added a discussion about your sentence.

Comment: A superb answer.

Answer (score 3):

Credit to @Janus Bahs Jacquet who posted the comment.

As far as ambiguity is concerned, context isn't everything: intonation and facial expression also play an important role in conveying exactly what we mean.

**In written English, however, context is everything** and it's easy for those who are writing to miss ambiguity in their own sentence.  That's why it's always wiser not to get into a heated debate in writing.

As for an ambiguous sentence, it's always possible to rewrite it and make your meaning unambiguous.  I would suggest the ambiguity to be disambiguated by separate and unrelated words. It's always possible to do that.

**The following sentence, for instance, should be avoided**: "was he driving on the right side of the road?"  It can be rephrased and one can substitute "right or left side?" or "right or wrong side?" to avoid ambiguity.

> A verb such as "expect" can easily be ambiguous in a sentence due to its not so different meanings.
>
> - **To consider likely or certain**: "I expect to see them soon."
> - **To consider reasonable or due**: "We expect an apology."
> - **To consider obligatory; require**: "The school expects its pupils to be on time."
> - **To presume; suppose**. (informal)    [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expect)

"I expect not to hear from you again" or a similar sentence as "I expect not to see you here when I return", meaning just an expectation but not a command, would be better written as:

- **"I don't expect to hear from you again"**
- "I don't expect to see you here when I return".

but you can always omit "expect" alltogether:

- **"I won't probably hear from you again"**
- "I won't probably see you here when I return."
- "I don't think you'll be here when I return."

If you really want to convey a command, then you can leave it as it is:

- **"I expect not to hear from you again."**

or even make it sound a little contentious changing the word order as suggested by BoldBen in his comment:

- **"I do not expect to hear from you again."** (you can always underline "do not")

Comment: More unambiguously non-commandy (but retaining _expect_) would be “I expect I won't hear from you again”. Although that, in turn, can be taken to express disappointment; as in “I wrote John a very polite message about it, but I expect I won't be hearing back from him”, where hearing back would be a positive thing, and it is mainly your knowledge of John’s character that makes you expect that he won't give you an answer.

Comment: There is also the other word order which has not been mentioned namely "I do not expect to hear from you again".  With this full word order it tends to have the 'order' connotation and to imply "If you contact me again, I'm calling my lawyer!" However if it is changed slightly to "I don't expect to hear from you again" or even more so "I don't expect that I shall hear from you again" it tends to become softer and imply "I free you from the obligation of further contact". This would be strengthened by adding "thank you for your help in this matter" or some similar phrase to the sentence.

Comment: @BoldBen  Good call !

Answer (score 0):

'I expect not to hear from you again' doesn't sound ambiguous to me.  It sounds clearly like your 'I expect you to tidy your room this evening' case.

If one wanted it to sound less imperative, one could say

> I expect I won't be hearing from you again.

This is actually ambiguous.  It could mean "leave me alone forever" or "I will understand if you don't want to have any more contact with me."  The context would make it clear, I think.

A non-ambiguous way of saying the latter would be

> I suppose I won't be hearing from you again.  I'm sorry about how things played out, but I understand.

However, the best way to convey that is not to say anything, and just let the person go his own way.